# How do I compile jrxml to get jasper?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

I have ***jrxml*** file, I want to compile this to get ***.jasper***. How do I compile and get that ***jasper*** file?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There are three ways to compile jrxml to jasper.

1. You can do direct compile via compile button (hammer logo) on iReport designer.
2. You can use ant to compile as shown in the [Ant Compile Sample](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/antcompile/index.html).

   ```
   <target name="compile1"> 
     <mkdir dir="./build/reports"/> 
     <jrc 
       srcdir="./reports"
       destdir="./build/reports"
       tempdir="./build/reports"
       keepjava="true"
       xmlvalidation="true">
      <classpath refid="runClasspath"/>
      <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>
     </jrc>
   </target>
   ```

   Below is the report compile task on my current project.

   [image]

   addition from [Daniel Rikowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23368/daniel-rikowski) :
3. You can also use the [JasperCompileManager](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperCompileManager.html) class to compile from your java code.

   ```
   JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(
                   "our_jasper_template.jrxml", // the path to the jrxml file to compile
                   "our_compiled_template.jasper"); // the path and name we want to save the compiled file to
   ```

Comment: Can you add how to link a datasource to example #3 ?

Comment: I suggest you add an image for #1 - the "hammer" logog... Picture makes it obvious.

Comment: iReport Designer is no longer supported. It is better to use Jaspersoft Studio now.

Comment: Please post your ant build.xml as text, not as image. It's truncated, and people cannot copy & paste it.

Answer (score 40):

For anyone coming across this question who uses [Jaspersoft Studio](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) (which, I think, is replacing iReports; it's quite similar, still freeware, just based on eclipse), look for the "Compile Report" icon on top of the editor area of your .jrxml file. Its icon, first in that line of icons, is a file with binary numbers on it (at least in version 5.6.2):

[image: Jaspersoft Studio - compile report]

Clicking this icon will generate the .jasper file in the same directory as the .jrxml file.

Comment: I wish that icon were smaller and more obscure

Answer (score 16):

with maven it is automatic:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}/WEB-INF/reports</outputDirectory>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <goals>
         <goal>compile-reports</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
       <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
       <version>3.7.6</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.16</version>
       <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: <phase>prepare-package</phase> is realy important if you are working with sping boot jar.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using iReport 2.0.2 to generate the jasper file.

I didn't found the hammer logo, but I have a menu `create > compile` in the menu bar who create the the jasper file in the iReport program files folder :

IReport Logs :"Compilation vers le fichier... .\SalesOrderItemsSubreportA4.jasper -> C:\Program Files\JasperSoft\iReport-2.0.2\SalesOrderItemsSubreportA4.java"

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @user35443, this is not a new question and actually provides an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 6):

In eclipse,

- Install [Jaspersoft Studio](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jaspersoft-studio) for eclipse.
- Right click the `.jrxml` file and select *`Open with JasperReports Book Editor`*
- Open the `Design` tab for the `.jrxml` file.
- On top of the window you can see the `Compile Report` icon.

Answer (score 5):

Using iReport designer 5.6.0, if you wish to compile multiple jrxml files without previewing - go to Tools -> Massive Processing Tool. Select Elaboration Type as "Compile Files", select the folder where all your jrxml reports are stored, and compile them in a batch.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using iReport you can easily do it.

1. When you click preview it will automatically compile.
2. There is an option to make it complie. You can compile by selecting the page then right click you will get the compile option.

Answer (score 3):

Using Version 5.1.0:

Just click preview and it will create a YourReportName.jasper for you in the same working directory.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your .jrxml file in iReport Designer.
2. Open the Report Inspector (Window -> Report Inspector).
3. Right-click your report name on the top of the inspector and then click "Compile Report".

You can also Preview your report so it's automatically compiled.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the eclipse IDE you just do a right click in the .jrxml file and then click the compile option

Answer (score 0):

```
 **A full example of POM file**.

Command to Build All **Jrxml** to **Jasper File** in maven
If you used eclipse then right click on the project and Run as maven Build and add goals antrun:run@compile-jasper-reports 


compile-jasper-reports is the id you gave in the pom file.
**<id>compile-jasper-reports</id>**




<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test.jasper</groupId>
  <artifactId>testJasper</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>TestJasper</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>       
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-jasper-reports</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="Start compile of jasper reports" />
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/classes/reports"/>
                            <echo message="${basedir}/src/main/resources/jasper/jasperreports" />
                            <taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask"
                                classpathref="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                <jrc srcdir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/jasper/jasperreports" destdir="${basedir}/src/main/resources/jasper/jasperclassfile"
                                  xmlvalidation="true">
                                <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                                <include name="**/*.jrxml" />
                            </jrc>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **iReport 5.5.0**, just ***right click*** the report base hierarchy in **Report Inspector** Bloc Window viewer, then click **Compile Report**

[image: In iReport, just right click the report base hierachy in Report]

You can now see the result in the console down. If no Errors, you may see something like this.

[image]