# Getting 3 mins to Generate the Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am developing the Invoice printing System using the Jasper report, Now I have can print the report but it will take 2000ms to load the report, also 2000ms take to start the printing, 
These are I am using the JAR FILES,

commons-beanutils-1.4 
commons-digester-1.7 
commons-logging-1.0.3 
commons-beanutils-1.4 
groovy-all-1.7.5 
batik-all-1.7 
barcode4j-2.1 
itextpdf-5.1.0 
jasperreports-6.0.3 
xercesImpl-2.11.0 
xml-apis-ext-1.3.04

```
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlString);
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    if (resultSet.next()) {

        HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();

        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(new File(
                "C:/Invoice/Invoice.jrxml"));

        JRDesignQuery designQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        designQuery.setText(sqlString);
        jasperDesign.setQuery(designQuery);

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                .compileReport(jasperDesign);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                jasperReport, null, conn);

        for (int i = 0; i < copies; i++) {

            JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, false);


        }

        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
```

The above code I used to print the report but, getting too much time to load the report. Please suggest my fault and some other idea...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the SQL query could be the problem. Have you tried executing it in a sql query tool and check how long it runs? Optimizing it should yield a performance win.

You are also running the query twice: before the report and when you are filling it via the JasperFillManager.fillReport() call.

If there are no specific reasons to check wheter the query contains any records, I would recommand to let JasperReports handle the query and the case that no record is found. You can determine a specific behaviour in that case via the "When No Data Type" property in the reportdesign.

Comment: I already check the SQL, it is executing fast. 
"You are also running the query twice: before the report and when you are filling it via the JasperFillManager.fillReport() call." I did not get this point, can you explain me this, 

This is I put the sample code. So, I have validate the When No Data Type, in my project.
When I debug this code, it takes too much time in these lines 
JRDesignQuery designQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
 JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                jasperReport, null, conn);

Comment: You should precompile the .jrxml into a .jasper file. This way, you can load it directly into an JasperReport object. Then you can pass the resultSet by wrapping it in an JRResultSetDataSource.

Comment: It should look something like this:
`preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sqlString);
     resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

     if (resultSet.next()) {
      resultSet.beforeFirst();
         JasperReport jasperReport = JRLoader.load(new File(
                 "C:/Invoice/Invoice.jasper"));         
         JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                 jasperReport, null, new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet));`

Comment: but I couldn't able to get the .jasper compiled report in my application. but if I create the new sample projects are showing the .jasper 
why is that ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456779/how-do-i-compile-jrxml-to-get-jasper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456779/how-do-i-compile-jrxml-to-get-jasper)

Comment: JasperReport jasperReport = JRLoader.load(new File( "C:/Invoice/Invoice.jasper")); Is this line working properly? because if I use this code then I got the below error 
The method load(File) is undefined for the type JRLoader 
I missed any jar?

Comment: `JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(new File( "C:/Invoice/Invoice.jasper"));`

Comment: Actually resultSet.beforeFirst() method we cannot use here, bcz
I will get an exception when I try to go back with beforeFirst(),
I got the exception below 
The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.

Comment: Then don't use resultSet.next() to check wether it's empty. [You can use resulset.isBeforeFirst() without moving the resultset-cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867194/java-resultset-how-to-check-if-there-are-any-results/6813771#6813771)