# JasperReport... What do you do First Compile or fill using parameters?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, servlet-3.0

I need to send parameters to my JasperReport.

Do I compile it first using `compileReport` and then call the `fillReport` passing the parameters or do I need to do things in the opposite order?

Comment: Generally, unless you are dynamic generating the structure of the report, you should compile once, maybe during your applications build cycle, and simply load and fill it at runtime

Comment: Do you mean to set my Parameters and invoke the fillReport Method when you said fill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling and filling report are two **different** things.

**About compiling**

Jasper reports is normally developed using IDE tools like iReport or JasperSoft Studio (you can also use a notepad), the report is saved in a file with the extension .jrxml, before running the `.jrxml` you need to compile it into a `.jasper` file (you can also compile on run time and only keep the `JasperReport` object)

It can be compared with the `.java` file that need's to be compiled into `.class` files before you can run the program.

For more information see:

[How do I compile jrxml to get jasper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456779/how-do-i-compile-jrxml-to-get-jasper)

**About filling**

Filling is when you like to fill your report design with data, the data can come from a [JRDatasource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html) or a database [Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) (query in report) and a `Map<String,Object>` parameter map. When report is filled you get a `JasperPrint` object (even this can be saved to file, to avoid filling same report multiple times)

**About export**

The final process in report generation is the export process, where you export the `JasperPrint` to your desired format pdf, excel, html etc.

So lets get back to your original question.

***Do I compile it first using `compileReport`?***

You can if you like to but you do **not need** to if you have already compiled your report, in this case just load the compiled report which is faster.

```
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(inputStream);
```