# Eclipse does not generate the .jasper file from .jrxml file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have installed the Jaspersoft Studio plugin from marketPlace. I created a java project and converted it to Maven to import the Jasper report jars. Afterwards I created a `Blank_A4.jrxml` file. Therefore, i added some java class from this tutorial

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_filling_reports.htm

as in the screenshot below.

The problem is when run the .jrxml file, there is nor .jasper file is being gernerated. Does anyone know what the problem is?

[image]

I have changed the path of`sourceFileName` in this class:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

public class JasperReportFill {
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String sourceFileName = 
            "C://Users/alex.tree/Documents/iReport Designer workspace/Blank_A4.jasper";

      DataBeanList DataBeanList = new DataBeanList();
      ArrayList<DataBean> dataList = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList();

      JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource =
      new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);

      Map parameters = new HashMap();
      /**
       * Passing ReportTitle and Author as parameters
       */
      parameters.put("ReportTitle", "List of Contacts");
      parameters.put("Author", "Prepared By Manisha");

      try {
         JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(
         sourceFileName, parameters, beanColDataSource);
      } catch (JRException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `The problem is when run the .jrxml file, there is nor .jasper file is being gernerated.` - What do you mean? What did you do for generating *.jasper* file?

Comment: Here is the answer. You need to compile report http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456779/how-do-i-compile-jrxml-to-get-jasper